# Horizontal alignment of pretitle

Tags: horizontal-alignment, titling

I'm writing a project relation and have pretty much achieved what I wanted. There is something that is bugging me and hav been trying to fix it but no luck. On the first page there are details of the university, the project name and other data; Unfortunatly it's not horizontaly alligned to the middle but slightly to the left, see the image below. I'm using the titling package.

The code:

```
% !Tex spellcheck = it_IT
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrbook}%{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,english,italian]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{BOONDOX-cal}
\usepackage{eucal}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[11pt]{moresize}
\usepackage{quoting, caption}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[autostyle,italian=guillemets]{csquotes}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\usepackage[
n,
operators,
advantage,
sets,
adversary,
landau,
probability,
notions,    
logic,
ff,
mm,
primitives,
events,
complexity,
asymptotics,
keys]{cryptocode}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linktoc=all,
    linkcolor=black
}

\quotingsetup{font=Large}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{teorema}{Teorema}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definizione}
\newtheorem{corollario}{Corollario}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\setcounter{section}{1}

\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\newcommand{\greco}[1]{
\begin{otherlanguage*}{greek}#1\end{otherlanguage*}}

\nocite{*}
\begin{document}
\pretitle{
    \begin{center}
    \vspace*{-8\baselineskip}
    \Huge{Università degli studi di Brescia} \\
    \huge{Facoltà di Ingegneria} \\
    \LARGE{Dipartimento di Ingegneria dell'Informazione} \\
    %\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\paperwidth}{0.4pt}}
    \vspace*{2\baselineskip}
    \LARGE
    \includegraphics[height=200px]{unibs.png} \\ [\bigskipamount]
    \vspace*{\baselineskip}
}

\posttitle{
    \end{center}
}

\preauthor{
\vspace*{5\baselineskip}
\begin{flushright}
\large
Docente:\\
Luca Giuzzi
\end{flushright}
\vspace*{-5\baselineskip}
\begin{flushleft}
\large
}
\postauthor{
\end{flushleft}
}
\title {CRYPTO RANSOMWARE \\ Analisi dei sistemi crypto ransomware}
\author{Sukhdev Mohan \\ matr. 86141}
\date{}

\begin{titlingpage}
    \maketitle
\end{titlingpage}

\newpage %\thispagestyle{empty}\mbox{} %void page for separation purpose
\vspace*{\fill}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{quoting}
\em{``Mathematical reasoning may be regarded rather schematically as the exercise of a combination of two facilities, which we may call intuition and ingenuity.''}
\medskip
\raggedleft
{\rightline{---Alan Turing}}
\end{quoting}
\vspace*{\fill}

\newpage
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\chapter{Introduzione} 
\input{intro}

\chapter{La matematica per cifrare Informazioni}
\input{cryptomath}
\section{Basi di Crittografia}
\input{basi-crypto}
\subsection{RSA}
\input{rsa}
\subsection{AES}
\input{aes}
\chapter{Prospettiva dell'attaccante}
\section{Impiego della Crittografia nella costruzione di applicazioni Malevole}
\input{applicazioni-malevole}
\section{Approfondimento: Crypto Ransomware}
\input{crypto-ransomware}
\section{Caso di Studio: Locky Crypto Ransoware}
\subsection{Dissezione}
\subsection{Diffusione}
\subsection{Infezione}
\subsection{Recupero}
\subsection{Pagamento: Bitcoin}
\subsection{Prevenzione}

\chapter{Conclusione}
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection

\printbibliography
\newpage

\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image]
How can I get into the middle of the page? thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a full compilable code (including document class, preamble, &c.)?

Comment: @Bernard thank you, I've editted the code and given the full one. I'm using scrbook as document class, there are included files that I've omitted please comment the \input. Thank you for the quick reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `\newgeometry` command at the very beginning of the `titlingpage` environment:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrbook}%{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,english,italian]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{BOONDOX-cal}
\usepackage{eucal}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[11pt]{moresize}
\usepackage{quoting, caption}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[autostyle,italian=guillemets]{csquotes}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
%\usepackage[
%n,
%operators,
%advantage,
%sets,
%adversary,
%landau,
%probability,
%notions,
%logic,
%ff,
%mm,
%primitives,
%events,
%complexity,
%asymptotics,
%keys]{cryptocode}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linktoc=all,
    linkcolor=black
}

\quotingsetup{font=Large}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{teorema}{Teorema}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definizione}
\newtheorem{corollario}{Corollario}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\setcounter{section}{1}

\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\newcommand{\greco}[1]{
\begin{otherlanguage*}{greek}#1\end{otherlanguage*}}
\usepackage{geometry}

\nocite{*}
\begin{document}
\pretitle{
    \begin{center}
    \vspace*{-8\baselineskip}
    \Huge{Università degli studi di Brescia} \\
    \huge{Facoltà di Ingegneria} \\
    \LARGE{Dipartimento di Ingegneria dell'Informazione} \\
    %\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\paperwidth}{0.4pt}}
    \vspace*{2\baselineskip}
    \LARGE
    \includegraphics[height=200px]{unibs.png} \\ [\bigskipamount]
    \vspace*{\baselineskip}
}

\posttitle{
    \end{center}
}

\preauthor{
\vspace*{5\baselineskip}
\begin{flushright}
\large
Docente:\\
Luca Giuzzi
\end{flushright}
\vspace*{-5\baselineskip}
\begin{flushleft}
\large
}
\postauthor{
\end{flushleft}
}
\title {CRYPTO RANSOMWARE \\ Analisi dei sistemi crypto ransomware}
\author{Sukhdev Mohan \\ matr. 86141}
\date{}

\begin{titlingpage}
\newgeometry{hmargin = 3cm}
    \maketitle
\end{titlingpage}
\newpage %\thispagestyle{empty}\mbox{} %void page for separation purpose
\vspace*{\fill}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{quoting}
\em{``Mathematical reasoning may be regarded rather schematically as the exercise of a combination of two facilities, which we may call intuition and ingenuity.''}
\medskip
\raggedleft
{\rightline{---Alan Turing}}
\end{quoting}
\vspace*{\fill}

\newpage
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\chapter{Introduzione}
\input{intro}

\chapter{La matematica per cifrare Informazioni}
\input{cryptomath}
\section{Basi di Crittografia}
\input{basi-crypto}
\subsection{RSA}
\input{rsa}
\subsection{AES}
\input{aes}
\chapter{Prospettiva dell'attaccante}
\section{Impiego della Crittografia nella costruzione di applicazioni Malevole}
\input{applicazioni-malevole}
\section{Approfondimento: Crypto Ransomware}
\input{crypto-ransomware}
\section{Caso di Studio: Locky Crypto Ransoware}
\subsection{Dissezione}
\subsection{Diffusione}
\subsection{Infezione}
\subsection{Recupero}
\subsection{Pagamento: Bitcoin}
\subsection{Prevenzione}

\chapter{Conclusione}
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection

\printbibliography
\newpage

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'll try tomorrow and will let you know. Thank you

Comment: Sorry I'm answering just now, but had a busy day, I tried and this is it! Thank you very much. Just a little question: what was the issue?

Comment: The problem seemed to come from left margin being  smaller than right margin, as is  traditional in good typography. So for the titling page I used package geometry, to have both margins equal to 3cmn so that the mid point of the text area is also the midpoint  of the physical sheet of paper.

Comment: Oh That's why. Does that in any way affect the other pages? just a concern

Comment: I don't think so,  because it's limited to the `titlingpage` environment – unless the simple loading  of `geometry` has an impact on `typearea`. I checked that in the following pages, the left and right margins were unequal again.